# AWS Neptune unable to load with Single cardinality

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I’m encountering an issue with the Neptune loader and as far as I can see I’m following the documentation correctly but I can’t get the Neptune Loader to load vertex information from CSVs correctly.

[Gremlin Neptune CSV Loader format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format-gremlin.html)

I’m using the latest version of Neptune and I’m setting the column data type and cardinality correctly but for some reason Neptune considers that all the properties on the loaded vertexes are SETs. Edge information is loaded correctly.

Please see below an example of how the headers/data look like. I’ve also tried quoting the headers and fields but to no avail. All the properties on the created vertexes are SETs.

[image]

As you can see below the loaded data does not have SINGLE cardinality.

[image]

Any ideas on how to convince Neptune to load data with the correct cardinality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Apache TinkerPop returns values in a `valueMap` as lists even if the cardinality is single. If you want to get rid of the list syntax you can do `valueMap().by(unfold())`

Edited to add text below:

If some of the values really are sets of values then you can selectively unfold only the ones that are not as in

`g.V('1').valueMap('myset','myint').by().by(unfold())`

There are more examples here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step

Comment: Thank you for the response Kelvin. Does this not have the side effect of converting  single value SETs to single cardinality and multi-value SETs to arrays? I'm concerned that this can even happen in the same query - essentially resulting in a different schema being returned depending on the number of elements stored in the SET?

Comment: I also noticed that valueMap() returns the correct cardinality for edges (single in my case). Does that mean that valueMap() has a different response schema on vertex vs edge?

Comment: I added to my answer to show how you can selectively unfold valueMap() items for the case where a property really is a set.

Comment: As defined by Apache TinkerPop Edges cannot have multi value properties (set,list)